# How to read in PAM module password entered by user

Tags: c, linux, authentication, pam

Is there some way to access password entered by non-local user during authentication in lightdm in PAM module? It is needed for further authentication in external API.

I tried to modify [pam-http module](https://github.com/1nfiniteloop/pam-http) and use pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, password). It returns 6 (Permission denied), and password is NULL.

My code is based on the existing pam-http module:

```
/* include PAM header files */
          
int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,
                                   int argc, const char **argv) {
    const void** authTok = NULL;
    // getting serviceName and userName
    statusCode = pam_get_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK, authTok);
    if (statusCode != PAM_SUCCESS || authTok == NULL || *authTok == NULL) {
        // writing statusCode and error message to syslog
        return statusCode;
    }
    // authenticating with API using userName and password
    return statusCode;
}

int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags,
                              int argc, const char **argv)
{
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know that my approach can be naive, but I really cannot find enough clues how to do it in the existing documentation.

Comment: Show your effort.  Post your code.  What you have does not include enough context to be helpful in understanding what problems you encountered.  ( [mcve] )

Comment: `pam_get_item()` returns integer status code, not a pointer. How can it return NULL?

Comment: That's, right, of course pam_get_item() returns integer, I've ment password is NULL. I've made a correction.